# Adding SWT Canvas to JPanel

Tags: canvas, swt, awt, swt-awt, nattable

I'm trying to add a NatTable (which extends org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas) to a JPanel (the majority of the program's graphics are in Swing, and I'm rather unfamiliar with SWT). I attempted to use the code below to test the SWT_AWT class, but I got an error:

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas canvas =
                new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas(
                        new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell(
                                Display.getDefault(),
                                1264),
                        SWT.NONE);
        java.awt.Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(canvas); //error here
        JPanel returnMe = new JPanel();
        returnMe.add(frame);

        return returnMe;
```

*Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid*

I do not understand why I have this error as I passed a SWT composite. Can anyone explain what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [In order for the embedding to succeed, the composite must have been created with the `SWT.EMBEDDED` style.](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/awt/SWT_AWT.html)

Also, you are going the other way: embedding Swing component in SWT. Instead you need

```
java.awt.Canvas canvas = ...
// assumes this code is running in SWT thread
Shell shell = SWT_AWT.new_Shell(Display.getCurrent(), canvas); 
NatTable table = new NatTable(shell, SWT.NONE); // etc.
```

Note that you need to arrange to run SWT code in SWT dispatch thread and Swing code in AWT dispatch thread.